# How to determine which object is moving relativistically?

Tags: special-relativity

Apologies in advance if I've overlooked some obvious point.
In relativity, I know that there is no way to know if Object A or Object B is moving relative to the other. Each would see themselves as stationary object. How does relativity know which object to apply the time dilation to?

Example: If a train moves at 99% the speed of light, we all know that time slows for people on the train. But since to those same people the Earth is moving 99% the speed of light, why does only the clock on the train slow down?

Comment: I think this exact questions bugged me for years. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox

Comment: here, all is symmetric. But, if one accelerates ...

Answer (score 4):

The clock in the train slows down as observed by people on earth.  The clock on earth slows down as observed by people on the train.  The situation is completely symmetric.  It all comes out of the [Lorentz transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation).

Answer (score 1):

Time dilation, length contraction, and every other relativistic affect is applied to the "other guy". Train A sees train B's time slowing down, and train B sees train A's time slowing down. Train A sees train B's length contracted, and train B sees train A's length contracted.

Comment: How is it then that time dilation could be measured with an atomic clock on an airplane flying once around the globe, and one "stationary"? By that logic, should (for the clock on the airplane) not the "stationary" clock have been slowed as well? (Yet only the "moving" one on the plane was slower.)